# sql server complex query in a view

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables named '`Delivery`' and '`PackageDelivery`'

In the table '`Delivery`' I have 2 columns `Delivery_ID` and `Delivery_Rank`

In the table `PackageDelivery` I have 2 columns `Package_ID` and `Delivery_ID`.

We can have more than delivery_ID for the same Package_ID in this table.
Consequently the Delivery_Rank in the table Delivery can increase as much as we have Delivery_id for the same Package_id

For example in the table PackageDelivery we have the following records:

```
1457 1589
1457 1590
1457 1591
```

the columns are respectively `package_id`, `delivery_id`

In the table Delivery we have the following records

```
1589 1
1590 2
1591 3
```

the columns are respectively `delivery_id` `delivery_rank`

I need with only one query to retrieve on the same line The package_id and the delivery_ID that have the lower Delivery_Rank and the Delivery_id that have the higher Delivery_Rank
For the example above I need to retrieve:

```
1457 1589 1591
```

The difficulties is that the query must be in a view and the desired package_id must be in the clause where outside the view

This is what I do:

```
with cte as(
select package_id,d.delivery_id, delivery_rank from packagedelivery pd inner join delivery d on pd.delivery_id=d.delivery_id where package_id=37453)
,cte2 as (
select top 1 delivery_id as firstdelivery_id ,package_id from cte order by delivery_rank asc)
,cte3 as(
select top 1 delivery_id as lastdelivery_id ,package_id from cte order by delivery_rank desc)

select distinct c1.package_id,c2.firstdelivery_id,c3.lastdelivery_id
from cte c1 inner join cte2 c2 on c1.Package_ID=c2.Package_ID
inner join cte3 c3 on c2.Package_ID=c3.Package_ID
```

But as I said the query must be put in a view and the package_id outside the view.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

### EDIT first answer was wrong...

My first attempt did not work correctly, if there are more than one package_ids in your PackageDelivery-Table. This should be better:

```
DECLARE @Delivery TABLE(delivery_id INT,delivery_rank INT);
DECLARE @PackageDelivery TABLE(package_id INT,delivery_id INT);

INSERT INTO @PackageDelivery VALUES
 (1457,1589)
,(1457,1590)
,(1457,1591)
,(1000,2000);

INSERT INTO @Delivery VALUES
 (1589,1)
,(1590,2)
,(1591,3)
,(2000,2);
```

--This is the code for your `VIEW`

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT pd.package_id
          ,d.delivery_id
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pd.package_id ORDER BY d.delivery_rank ASC ) AS SortUp
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pd.package_id ORDER BY d.delivery_rank DESC) AS SortDown
    FROM @PackageDelivery AS pd
    INNER JOIN @Delivery AS d on pd.delivery_id=d.delivery_id
)
SELECT n.package_id
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN SortUp=1 THEN n.delivery_id END) AS MinRank
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN SortDown=1 THEN n.delivery_id END) AS MaxRank
FROM Numbered AS n
GROUP BY n.package_id
```

Outside you can set the `package_id` with a `WHERE`

Another -maybe better - approach was an inline TVF with the package_id as parameter...

Comment: Thanks a lot Shnugo it works!!  have you a solution if the Min(Delivery_Rank) is not 1 (for example 2 or 3)?

Comment: @user3569267, the additional package (id=1000) with delivery (id=2000) has got only one line with rank 2. In this case this one line is placed as **min and as max**. My code is using `ROW_NUMBER` to get a gap-less sort ASC and a secod time DESC. The number 1 must be the first in both ranks, no matter what rank you put actually...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher then I would simply stick to using the Min and Max windowing function. The following example shows an example of a view for your specific problem.

```
CREATE VIEW MyPackageView
AS
SELECT      package_id
            ,MIN(delivery_id) AS min_delivery_id
            ,MAX(delivery_id) AS max_delivery_id
FROM        (
                SELECT      P.package_id
                            ,P.delivery_id
                            ,D.delivery_rank
                            ,MIN(D.delivery_rank) OVER (PARTITION BY P.package_id) AS min_delivery_rank
                            ,MAX(D.delivery_rank) OVER (PARTITION BY P.package_id) AS max_delivery_rank
                FROM        PackageDelivery P
                INNER JOIN  Delivery D ON P.delivery_id = D.delivery_id
            ) RankedPackageDelivery
WHERE       (delivery_rank = min_delivery_rank) OR (delivery_rank = max_delivery_rank)
GROUP BY    package_id
```